# highcharts js move series data container up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using highcharts + `highcharts-ng` and I'm trying to position the container for series Data (where the number 80 appears below) a little bit higher since it is overlapping with numbers 200 and -200 in the ticks. I looked in the docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cgauge%3E) and [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style) but could not find the relevant info, I also tried everything in the comments in the code below but it did not work - what option do I need to do this? here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/8Cx5s/63/

[image]

```
 series: [{
      name: 'Credit Used',
      // xAxis: 2,
      // yAxis: 2,
      zIndex: 2,
      data: [80],
      tooltip: {

      },
       // spacingBottom: 15,
       // align: 'left'
      // position: {y:2},
      // x:2,
      // y:2,
      // marginBottom: 5
  }]
```

Comment: did you check the configuration http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer ?

Comment: I sure did. I finally found it here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cgauge%3E.dataLabels. I will update with my answer + and an updated fiddle

Comment: Awesome. Good that you have found the solution,

Comment: You might also want to try different values for the `startAngle` and `endAngle` (for eg: -130 to 130).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the `dataLabels` object. here is the updated fiddle in case it helps anyone else:
http://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/8Cx5s/65/